# How to get row of data frame in R

Tags: r

See the following code

```
> df<-data.frame(x=c(4,4,5))
> rownames(df)<-c(9,3,8)
> df
  x
9 4
3 4
8 5
> y<-c(8)
> df[y[1],]
[1] NA
```

I understand the problem, but I don't know the solution.  How do I reference the last row  of df (or any row in general) using the vector y?  This is a simplified version of a bigger problem, so no giving easy work-arounds like df[3,] or df[NROW(df),].  You must use y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, convert `y` to character:

```
R> y <- as.character(y)
R> df[y[1],]
[1] 5
```

This works because rownames are always character.  See for yourself via:

```
R> rownames(df)
[1] "9" "3" "8"
```

Your attempt failed because you were asking for the 8th row of a data.frame that only has 3 rows.